# Export QGIS print layout to PDF from script or command line

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, pdf

The "GUI way" of exporting a map to a PDF in QGIS's layout manager is known to be `Layout -> Export as PDF ...`.

I wonder if there is any way to do this the CLI way. Either from a python script or the shell. Does anybody know how one would achieve this, especially since QGIS 3.14 added CLI support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from script you can do it with the following code fragment:

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
#layout = manager.layoutByName("Layout1")  # name of the layout 
layout = manager.layouts()[0]  # or first layout

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf("d:/layout.pdf",
         QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```